# How to change network mask using ip command

Tags: linux, networking, ip, interface

I tried to change the network mask using Linux ip command and got confused. Google search doesn't clarify it either. If someone could explain? Say I have interface **enp0s31f6** on my Linux machine

```
rtuser@rtuser:~$ ip addr show dev enp0s31f6
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:fa:9b:c7:37:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I want to assign ip address to the interface:

```
rtuser@rtuser:~$ sudo ip addr add 192.168.20.1/24 dev enp0s31f6
rtuser@rtuser:~$ ip addr show dev enp0s31f6
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:fa:9b:c7:37:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.20.1/24 scope global enp0s31f6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Now I realized that my network mask is not correct, I want to change

```
rtuser@rtuser:~$ sudo ip addr change 192.168.20.1/25 dev enp0s31f6
rtuser@rtuser:~$ ip addr show dev enp0s31f6
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:fa:9b:c7:37:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.20.1/24 scope global enp0s31f6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.20.1/25 scope global enp0s31f6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I got couple same ip addresses on interface. Well, maybe change doesn't work lets try to replace it

```
rtuser@rtuser:~$ sudo ip addr replace 192.168.20.1/26 dev enp0s31f6
rtuser@rtuser:~$ ip addr show dev enp0s31f6
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:fa:9b:c7:37:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.20.1/24 scope global enp0s31f6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.20.1/25 scope global enp0s31f6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.20.1/26 scope global enp0s31f6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I would expect change/replace ip command would change properties of ip address, but it seems they all add/change/replace keep adding the same ip over and over again. Why is that?

Comment: Delete the ones you don't want by changing `add` to `del`. E.g. `sudo ip addr del 192.168.20.1/24 dev enp0s31f6`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Using del command is quite obvious. It'll do what it's supposed to do - deleting ip address. I just want to understand the behavior and reasons for that behavior. Seems like add/change/replace commands do the same thing. I don't believe those smart people who developed ip command would put such duplication with no reason.

Comment: the object the command applies a change effect upon is not 192.168.20.1 but the whole 192.168.20.1/24. Using change (or replace) can't affect the object's value itself, only other properties of the object (such as valid_lft), though most can't be changed anyway.

Comment: This question is answered well here: https://serverfault.com/a/666521/90281

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the original, erroneous entry with the del option.

```
ip address del 192.168.20.1/24 dev enp0s31f6
```

And then add the corrected IP/CIDR:

```
ip address add 192.168.20.1/25 dev enp0s31f6
```

Comment: I needed to do this remotely, so *BEFORE* deleting the address, I created a temporary address, checked if it worked, when OK, I removed and fixed the previous address, then removed the temporary address. It worked just fine. Thanks for providing the answer with `ip` instead of `ifconfig` :)

Comment: How do you make it permanent? Reboots reset the settings back to default. The machine has network-manager installed, but it doesn't change the network settings after a reboot.

Comment: OK, so I [added a new connection and brought it up with `nmcli`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1466086/959929) to make it survive a reboot. But please feel free to let us know if there is another way to make this change permanent with the `ip` command.